# Linear Algebra(Vector Space)

Tags: vector-spaces

Determine whether each of the following sets can be made into a vector space
a)The set of all 2x2 matrices with trace zero(the trace of a matrix is the sum of the entries on the main diagonal)

Comment: "Each of the following" ? Where are the other choices?

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\begin{cases}Tr.(A+B)=Tr.(A)+Tr.(B)\\{}\\Tr.(kA)=k\,Tr.(A)\;,\;\;k\in\text{ the field}\end{cases}\;\;\implies\;\text{you have a subspace here}$$